# right aligned text in a input

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I'm  working on a website the designer placed some extra text in a input form 
[image]

my code:

```
<form id="hmail">
    <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="on" type="text" name="register" id="getemail" value="your company" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
    <input type="submit" id="sendmail" value="Claim">
</form>
```

i was thinking some thing like value="...dock.com" and float right ?
only i cant seem to get this working

Comment: Does "dock.com" has to disappear on focus as well or should it always be there?

Comment: it needs to be there always :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement "dock.com" as a background image via CSS; something like:

```
background-image:url(dockimage.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-position:right;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the background image to the text like so:

```
input[name=theName] {
    background: #fff url(path/to/bg.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}
```

And set a max-length on the input to prevent the input's text going over the background.

Comment: `maxlength` is unreliable for that. Compare llllllllll with WWWWWWWWWW (both 10 characters). Instead, use `padding-right` with a value a little bigger than the background image width.

Comment: working for me with no-repeat right center only i agree with the padding-right is a better solution